Intuitions in philosophy, boon or bane?
Assuming that intuitions are often wrong, are they useful at advancing philosophy or a hindrance? Daniel Dennett coined the term intuition pump , a thought experiment that helps the reader to develop an intuition for the right explanation of a phenenomon. However,:

he uses the term to describe John Searle's Chinese room thought experiment, characterizing it as designed to elicit intuitive but incorrect answers by formulating the description in such a way that important implications of the experiment would be difficult to imagine and tend to be ignored.

Earlier, Dennett has defended the use of intuition pumps:

Intuition pumps are cunningly designed to focus the reader's attention on "the important" features, and to deflect the reader from bogging down in hard-to-follow details. There is nothing wrong with this in principle.

Intuitions are useful in daily life (or are they?) and mostly, I would claim, the result of what Kahneman calls System I thinking. These entrenched intuitions then transport to our philosophical thinking.
My question is: should we be hesitant about using intuition pumps? Should intuition pumps come with a warning?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

To quote Einstein: "Imagination is more important than knowledge". Intuition is essential for seeing past that which everyone already knows, and discovering that which people don't know. Intuition can sometimes lead one astray — which is why analytical methods are important — but without intuition nothing new will ever come to light.

Are intuition and imagination the same thing though?

@local There's nothing wrong with the answer. I upvoted. Just curious because of the Einstein quote. I think there's a relation between imagination and intuition, but I can't really parse it. That's all. There's also the thing where I thought intuition is more about accepting or denying a point of view, rather than moving forward. That's why I was pleased with the answer.

@Philomath: Intuition is imagination grounded in observation: the ability to see what other people see but draw more from it. Everyone can see the sun rise; it takes intuition to think the earth might be turning. But I think it's clear that's what E meant. He wasn't talking about art or fantasy, but about the creative process that lies behind the sciences.
